# Identify working location events from Google Apps Script CalendarApp.getEvents

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that finds all recurring events and changes their color. This code has been working for months and it recently stopped working.

It is breaking because now, all of a sudden, it is also returning working location events -- and you can't change the color of working location events.

So I am trying to find a way to determine if an event is a working location.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  var nextWeek = new Date(today);
  nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 7);

  CalendarApp.getEvents(today, nextWeek).forEach(event => {
    if(event.isRecurringEvent())
    {
      Logger.log(event.getTitle());
      Logger.log(event.getDescription());
      Logger.log(event.getStartTime());
      Logger.log(event.getEndTime());
      
      event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.ORANGE);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What does mean `working location events`?

Comment: Please explain why this is true. `It is breaking because now, all of a sudden, it is also returning working location events -- and you can't change the color of working location events.`

Comment: What's a working location  event and why is it different from other events. We don't know about you WIP we just answer scripting questions.

Comment: @Antonio Google Calendar recently introduced work location. See https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/7638168.

Comment: @Cooper See comment above for information on work location. Now, when you call `CalendarApp.getEvents`, it also returns work location events. And for those events, you can't set the color -- either through the GUI or GAS.

Comment: Try raising it as a feature request "
- [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)
"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no method available in the basic Calendar event class to get the event type.

But you can use AppScript Advanced services (Google Calendar API) to get the eventType - https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get

It has workingLocation as one of the possible values.

[image]